# Getting duplicate change notifications in gulp from Gaze when watching multiple file sets

Tags: gulp

We're using gulp with Gaze to watch files/directories for changes.  We need to watch two separate sets of files and run different tasks for each set if there are changes.

The problem is that changes in one file set are triggering both watches.

Here's a minimal gulpfile which exhibits the behavior

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  Gaze = require('gaze').Gaze;

gulp.task('watch', function () {

  function watch(paths, taskToRun) {
    new Gaze(paths, {mode: 'poll'}).on('all', function(event, filename) {
      console['log']('Change detected - in '+filename+' for event '+event+' for task watcher '+taskToRun);
    });
  }

  watch(['foo/**/*.js'], 'jstask1');
  watch(['bar/**/*.js'], 'jstask2');

});
```

I set it up by running

```
npm install gulp gaze 
touch foo/a.js
touch bar/b.js
gulp watch
```

In a separate terminal I ran

```
touch foo/a.js
```

and I get

```
[12:51:33] Using gulpfile ~/tmp/gaze/gulpfile.js
[12:51:33] Starting 'watch'...
[12:51:33] Finished 'watch' after 13 ms
Change detected - in /home/foo/tmp/gaze/foo/a.js for event changed for task watcher jstask1
Change detected - in /home/foo/tmp/gaze/foo/a.js for event changed for task watcher jstask2
```

Both jstask1 and jstask2 were triggered.  I would expect only the jstask1 should have fired since jstask2's path doesn't match.

We're using Gaze as we're running this for development inside of vagrant on multiple platforms (OSX and Linux) using on VirtualBox using the VirtualBox file sharing for the source directories.  We had problems with other methods properly detecting the addition and removal of files.  This particular test was done directly on my linux box (no vagrant involved) but we see the same issues inside of vagrant as well.

Is this a bug or or am I setting up Gaze wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround for the issue.  Still seems like the behavior of Gaze isn't correct, but if I use the minimatch library directly within the event callback, I can check if the filename matches one the paths I really wanted for that particular task.  If it matches, then I can run the desired task and otherwise ignore the event.

Here's the updated example from above

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
  Gaze = require('gaze').Gaze,
  Minimatch = require("minimatch").Minimatch;

gulp.task('watch', function () {

  function watch(paths, task) {
    //check for bare strings instead of arrays
    if(typeof paths == 'string') {
      paths=[paths];
    }

    var cwd=process.cwd();
    var len=paths.length;
    var minimatchPaths=[];
    for(var i=0; i < len; i++) {
      var path = paths[i];
      minimatchPaths.push(new Minimatch(cwd + '/' + path));
    }

    function checkPaths(filename) {
      var len=minimatchPaths.length;
      for(var i=0; i < len; i++) {
        var minimatchPath = minimatchPaths[i];
        if(minimatchPath.match(filename)) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    new Gaze(paths, {mode: 'poll'}).on('all', function(event, filename) {
      if(checkPaths(filename)) {
        console.log(event+' detected on '+filename+' for '+ task);
      }
    });
  }

  watch(['foo/**/*.js'], 'jstask1');
  watch(['bar/**/*.js'], 'jstask2');

});
```